# Applying layout to an item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a messaging app where I want to display incoming messages and messages sent with two different layouts.  Both use the same adapter here is my code...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the item (send message) I add to my listview dynamically

```
   post_message_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TextView username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conversation_username2);

                convoItems.add(new ConversationItem(1656, 1, "Bob Doe", DateTime.now(), write_message.getText().toString()));

                convoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (v.getId() == R.id.send_message_button);
                write_message.setText("");

            }
        });
        convoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(ConversationView.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                  //      .show();
            }
        });
```

Here is my adapter I want the onClick to use layout 2

```
if (convertView == null) {


                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate
                        (R.layout.conversation_list_item, parent, false);

                //Username
                TextView username = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.conversation_username);
                username.setText(items.get(position).convoUsername);

                //Date Time
                TextView dateTime = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.conversation_date);
                dateTime.setText(items.get(position).DateTimeStamp.toString());

                //Message
                TextView message = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.conversation_message);
                message.setText(items.get(position).Message);
            } else {

                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate
                        (R.layout.activity_conversation_item_send, parent, false);

                //Username
                TextView username = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.conversation_username2);
                username.setText(items.get(position).convoUsername);

                //Date Time
                TextView dateTime = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.conversation_date2);
                dateTime.setText(items.get(position).DateTimeStamp.toString());

                //Message
                TextView message = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.conversation_message2);
                message.setText(items.get(position).Message);

            }
```

Comment: Be more precise. What really do you want to do?

Comment: I have dummy data for received messages  which uses the first layout in my getView method.  The app can also send messages which are dynamically written and which also use the same layout however I want them to use the layout written after else.

Comment: Are you still working on this issue? Anyway you already have 2 layouts, conversation_list_item and activity_conversation_item_send. What else do you require?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way for you to do this is to store a flag in your `ConversationItem` that tells if the item is a dummy item or created dynamically. (An alternaive way would be to subclass your `ConversationItem` class to distinguish between the two different types of items.)

Add a new if case to check the flag is true or false. But don't forget to keep the check if the `convertView` is null, for both cases, and inflate the correct layout file if needed.

Please note that If the `convertView` isn't null that just means that an already inflated view will be reused.